# What is the geometric interpretation of the following equation?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

What is the geometric interpretation of the following equation?

$\displaystyle\left|\frac{1+z}{1-i\bar{z}}\right|=1$

Answer (score 8):

$|1+z|=|1-i\bar{z}|=|1+iz|=|-i+z|$. Hence $z$ has the same distance between $(-1,0)$ and $(0,i)$ . Thus $z$ has the form $t(-1+i), t\in \mathbb{R}$, lies on line $t(-1+i), t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be transformed to
$$
|1 + z| = |1 -i \bar{z}| \quad (*)
$$

which implies for the squares of the lengths:
$$
|1 + z|^2 = |1 -i \bar{z}|^2 \iff \\
(1+z)(1+\bar{z}) = (1-i\bar{z})(1+i z) \iff \\
1 + z + \bar{z} + z \bar{z} =1 + iz - i\bar{z} + z \bar{z} \iff \\
z + \bar{z} = i (z -\bar{z}) \iff \\
\frac{z + \bar{z}}{2} =  \frac{i (z -\bar{z})}{2} = -\frac{z -\bar{z}}{2i} \iff \\
\mbox{re } z + \mbox{im z} = 0
$$

Switching to cartesian coordinates $z = x + i y$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ this is
equivalent to $x + y = 0$
or as real valued linear function
$$ 
y(x) = -x
$$

Switching back to complex numbers, we can equivalently say that $z$ lies on the line 
$$
(1-i)t \quad (**)
$$ 
with $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Another way to interpret $(*)$ geometrically is
\begin{align}
|1 + z | &= |z - (-1 + 0 i)| = r_1 \\
|1 -i \bar{z}| &= |\overline{1 -i \bar{z}}| = |1 + i z|= |i||-i + z| = |z - (0+i)| = r_2
\end{align}
The first equation describes a circle with center $(-1,0)$, the second a circle with center $(0,1)$. Both circles, if having the same radius $r$ each, intersect at two points, all intersection points form the line $(**)$ given above. Here is a plot for $r = 10$ and $r = 5$.

[image: intersecting circles]

Answer (score 1):

John ZHANG provided a nice analytic description of the fact that this equation represents a line.  Here's a command to visualize it with Mathematica, that [works in Wolfram Alpha](http://goo.gl/1jn5id) as well.

```
ContourPlot[Abs[(1+(x+I*y))/(1-I(x-I*y))]==1,{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]
```

[image]